# ajax to php to curl and back

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, rss, curl

I am trying to make an ajax call to a php script. The php script calls an rss feed using curl, gets the data, and returns the data to the funciton.

I keep getting an error

"**Warning**:  Wrong parameter count for curl_error() in"  ....

Here is my php code:1

```
$ch = curl_init() or die(curl_error());
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $feed);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $data1 = curl_exec($ch) or die(curl_error());
        echo $data1;
```

and the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({ 
                       url: "getSingleFeed.php", 
                       type: "POST",
                       data: "feedURL=" + window.feedURL,
                       success: function(feed){

                    alert(feed);

                    }});
```

I tested all the variables, they are being passed correctly, I can echo them out. But this line:  $data1 = curl_exec($ch) or die(curl_error());

is what is giving me the error.  I am doing the same thing with curl on other pages, just without ajax, and it is working fine. Is there anything special I need to do with ajax to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The PHP manual](https://www.php.net/curl_error) states that the first parameter of curl_error is a handle returned by curl_init();. Try replacing what you pasted with what is given below. This adds the $ch variable as a parameter to all the instances of curl_error();.

```
$ch = curl_init() or die(curl_error($ch));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $feed);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $data1 = curl_exec($ch) or die(curl_error($ch));
        echo $data1;
```

Comment: Of course that will probably give an runtime error if curl_init fails because $ch will have the value False which is not the correct type.

Comment: same thing. Like I said, the curl script works fine just in php. It's once I call it from ajax that it doesn't work.

Comment: Make it 'replace the curl_error() in the 4th line with curl_error($ch) and we have an answer...

Comment: there she goes... so, does it just handle errors differently?

Comment: No, probably $feed is wrong, but curl will tell you as soon as you add that $ch to it's curl_error() function.